# How to convert tags in HTML using AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I am getting a JSON using AJAX in AngularJS. One of the attributes in the object  (say, *sample*), has a string "<b>String</b>".

I populate this into a table as follows:
<td>{{item.sample}} </td>

This gives an output: `<b>String</b>` on the webpage, when I was actually trying to display **String**.

Since it is a JSON string, what is currently happening makes sense. How do I use this string and somehow evaluate it so that I see the bold string on the webpage?

Comment: check out bind html https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) directive to render your text.

```
<td ng-bind-html="item.sample"></td>
```